# Unknown conditional expression and operators

Tags: bash

I needed bash to source my .bashrc upon login to a new terminal on my mac (because it doesn't do that upon login to a new terminal on macs, it only does .bash_profile).  I found and successfully used this command and added it to my .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] && [ "${SHELL##*/}" == "bash" ]
then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

There are three things about this command I don't understand.

1. What does the -f mean in the first condition?
2. What does the ##/ indicate in the second condition?
3. I understand that ". ~/.bashrc" is meant to have the shell source that rc, but how in the world does that command accomplish this?  What is the "." supposed to indicate here?

Answer (score 3):

1. `-f` is a predicate that tests to see if a particular file (~/.bashrc in this case) exists.
2. `##*/` as part of a variable substitution means remove something ending in "/" from the beginning of the variable's value -- for example, if SHELL were "/usr/local/bin/bash", it'd remove the "/usr/local/bin/" and just give "bash".  In detail: `##` means remove the longest match possible of what follows, `*/` matches anything ending in "/".

   Other related options: `#` means remove the shortest match (i.e. `#*/` would remove through the *first* "/"), `%%` means remove the longest possible match from the *end*, and `%` means remove the shortest match from the end.
3. `.` is a shorter name for the `source` command -- a shell built-in command that executes the contents of a script (~/.bashrc in this case) in the current shell.  Normally, if you run a shell script, it's run in a subshell and any variables, aliases, functions etc that it defines are lost when it exits; by `source`ing it instead, things it defines are valid in the current shell.

Answer (score 1):

1) checks to make sure the file ~/.bashrc exists

2) ${SHELL} is a variable that contains the full path of the current shell. If you type `echo $SHELL` or `echo ${SHELL}` at a terminal, it will print the path. ${SHELL##*/} removes the path and just prints the file name. Type `echo ${SHELL##*/}` in a terminal to see.

3) the period "." is a built-in bash command to run a script in the current process. I.E. it sources a file.

---

So that line basically says, "if the file ~/.bashrc exists and the current shell is a bash shell, then source ~/.bashrc"

My ~/.bash_profile just contains:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```